# Error in acessing results in a relational database

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

i have a table setup as the folowing

[image]

I am trying to write one query to return the result where status=1 confirmed =1 and user ID=specified. I want the result to dispay the user id , the name associated to that user id, the freind id and the name associated to that freind id. So far following tutorials on the web i have come up with the following query

```
SELECT `freinds.User ID`, `freinds.Freind ID`, `users.User`, `users.User` FROM `freinds` WHERE `User ID`= 6 INNER JOIN `users` on `users.ID`=6 AND `users.ID`=`freinds.Freind ID`
```

However i am getting an sql error with this query. I think what i am supposed to do is Inner join the user table twice but i am not exactly sure as to how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is you have wrap the tablename and columnname with backtick as a whole. you need to separate it, or if the name is not on `MySQL Reserved Keywords, remove the backticks.

You also need to join the table `User` twice so you can get the names for each ID on table `Freinds`.

```
SELECT  a.`User ID`, 
        a.`Freind ID`, 
        b.User FriendName,
        c.User UserName
FROM    `freinds` a
        INNER JOIN `users` b 
            ON b.ID = a.`Freind ID`
        INNER JOIN users c
            ON c.id = a.`user ID`
WHERE   `User ID`= 6
```

As a sidenote, if one of the `ID` is *nullable*, `LEFT JOIN` is preferred than `INNER JOIN`.

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: thanks a lot. solved my problems in a second. And thanks for the link as well

Comment: i was wondering if you could explain to me whya nd how you have used the 'a','b'and  'c's?

Comment: They are called `ALIAS`. They are helpful when you have longer tablenames which is hard to type. So instead of tablenames you can use `ALIAS` instead.